# Does the Golden Knife have different stats than the regular knife?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

When you are at the last level of the Arms Race mode, are you on an advantage or disadvantage with other players with a normal knife?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - the golden knife has the more specific purpose of ending the Arms Race - the knife is gold to convey to the user the difference between killing someone with a knife to steal their level and killing someone with a knife to win the game.

It provides you with no advantage or disadvantage other than winning the game if you kill with it.

Comment: [Source from CS:GO beta patch notes](http://store.steampowered.com/news/7738/).

Comment: Quick question, what do you mean "steal their level"? DO you mean automatically be at that player's weapon level? Or is it just taking it away?

Comment: @lumbricuslubricant According to [this wiki](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Arsenal:_Arms_Race#Arsenal:_Arms_Race), killing someone with a non-golden knife will cause them to lose a level (while you, as usual, gain one for your kill). Interesting; I hadn't noticed that either.